# mesclar dataframe por linhas

Tags: r, dataframe

tenho 2 data frames e gostaria de mesclar um data frame com outro data frame pela coluna de valores, fazendo uma subtração dos valores de cada linha.
Os data frames que tenho são :

df1:

```
   UF  Ano   Valor
    1 AC 2007 2315798
    2 AC 2008 2425687
    3 AC 2009 2511285
    4 AC 2010 2578460
    5 AC 2011 2549497
    6 AC 2012 2634467
```

df2:

```
   UF   Ano  Valor
    1 AC  2007 446447
    2 AC  2008 417316
    3 AC  2009 418318
    4 AC  2010 485166
    5 AC  2011 455485
    6 AC  2012 362548
```

Gostaria de criar um outro data frame apartir destes, em que tenha a coluna UF, Ano e Valor, porém a coluna Valor feita a subtração de df1-df2.

ou seja, gostaria que ficasse assim :

```
  UF   Ano  Valor
1 AC  2007 1869351
2 AC  2008 2008371
3 AC  2009 2092967
4 AC  2010 2033294
5 AC  2011 2094012
6 AC  2012 2271919
```

Answer (score 2):

Em R base, pode-se fazer isso com `merge`.

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c('UF', 'Ano'))
df3[[3]] <- df3[[3]] - df3[[4]]
df3 <- df3[-4]
df3
#  UF  Ano Valor.x
#1 AC 2007 1869351
#2 AC 2008 2008371
#3 AC 2009 2092967
#4 AC 2010 2093294
#5 AC 2011 2094012
#6 AC 2012 2271919
```

Com o pacote `dplyr` poderá ser assim:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c('UF', 'Ano')) %>%
  mutate(Valor = Valor.x - Valor.y) %>%
  select(UF, Ano, Valor)
```

**Dados.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
UF  Ano   Valor
1 AC 2007 2315798
2 AC 2008 2425687
3 AC 2009 2511285
4 AC 2010 2578460
5 AC 2011 2549497
6 AC 2012 2634467
", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
UF   Ano  Valor
1 AC  2007 446447
2 AC  2008 417316
3 AC  2009 418318
4 AC  2010 485166
5 AC  2011 455485
6 AC  2012 362548
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Olá, usando o merge, não está fazendo a mesclagem, veja: [1] UF      Ano     Valor.x Valor.y
<0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0)
>

Comment: @IngledSeiévini Está usando o `merge` tal como está na resposta? Em particular, o argumento `by = c('UF', 'Ano')` não pode incluir a coluna `Valor`. O resultado acima foi obtido com os dados tal e qual estão na pergunta e funciona.

Comment: Sim, estou usando o merge como está, não estou incluindo a coluna Valor. O dados são os mesmos, dei somente um head e colei aqui, o data frame só é um pouco maior. quando abro o novo data frame depois que executei o merge , aparece 3 colunas de UF, Ano, Valor.x e Valor.y, e uma mensagem de "No data invailable in table".